# How to replace string begining with @@ only and not @ or @@@?

Tags: php, regex, string

Consider the string

```
$str="hello @jack, tell @sam,@@jake and @@sam and @@@jake and @tom/@jim and @@jake hello"
```

Is it possible to replace a specific username (for example jack) that begins with `@@` only and not `@` or `@@@`?

What I mean is that, is it possible to only effect a string beginning with a specific number of `@`?

This is what I tried

```
$user = "jack";
$str = preg_replace('~@@'.$user.'~', '[['.$user.']]', $str);
```

the problem is that this replaces both `@@jack` and `@@@jack` with **jack** and `@`**jack**.

Comment: Use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). What's the point of scanning for one fixed name after the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the necessary number of `@` and use a negative [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
(?<!@)@@jake\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hK8dQ1/2). This will match `jake` as a whole word (due to word boundary `\b`) preceded with only 2 `@`s (as the `(?<!@)` negative look-behind checks if there is a `@` before the first `@`, and if yes, does not match the first `@`).

To match a word preceded with only 4 `@` symbols, use `(?<!@)@{4}word\b`. For only one `@`, use `(?<!@)@word\b`.

Sample [code demo](http://ideone.com/Vo4SF7):

```
$str="hello @jack, tell @sam,@@jake and @@sam and @@@jake and @tom/@jim and @@jake hello";
$user = "jake";
$number_of_prefixes = 2;
$str = preg_replace('~(?<!@)@{' . $number_of_prefixes . '}'.$user.'\b~', '[['.$user.']]', $str);
echo $str;
```

Output: `hello @jack, tell @sam,[[jake]] and @@sam and @@@jake and @tom/@jim and [[jake]] hello`

Comment: Thank you, just for curiosity, how would `(?<!@)@@jake\b` change If for example we wanted to only change a string that begins only with  four `@@@@` or a string that begins with only one `@`.

Comment: To match a word preceded with only 4 `@`s, use `(?<!@)@{4}word\b`. For only one `@`, `(?<!@)@word\b`. Note that the last `\b` is only good for words ending with `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If there can be a non-word character, the pattern won't match. Maybe [this demo](http://ideone.com/A85ZQv) could be of interest to you, where you can specify the number of prefixed symbols as a variable.